# Trying to build dynamic menu from a static one using Templates

Tags: c#, css, templates, dynamic, menu

I am trying to build, from a static menu, with pre-defined CSS classes into a dynamic one, using the .NET/C# 'Templates', specifically to EPiServer.

[Information on PageTree](http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/08/episerver-web-controls-menulist-and-pagetree/)

I am not technical at all, more front end, but been asked to do this project.

Menu code is here.

```
<ul onClick="" class="zetta-menu zm-effect-fade">
<li style="margin-left: 185px;">
<a href="http://intranet/en/Web-Developments-draft/Marc-Testing/Self-Help/">Self-help
<i class="zm-caret fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
<ul class="w-300">
     <li><a href="http://intranet/en/Web-Developments-draft/Marc-Testing/Self-Help/Email/">Email</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li> 
 <li>
   <a href="#">Clinical Systems
   <i class="zm-caret fa fa-angle-down"></i>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Equipment
  <i class="zm-caret fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Training
  <i class="zm-caret fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
<li>
  <a href="#">Performance
  <i class="zm-caret fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
<li>
  <a href="#">About us
  <i class="zm-caret fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="w-300">
     <li><a href="#">Information Governance</a></li>
  <ul class="zm-drop-left w-300">
           <li><a href="#">Drop down</a></li>

           </ul>


  </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>

<br class="clear" />
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid to start with...perhaps running it through a validator might be a good place to start.

Comment: Fair point, have updated.

Comment: Ok...http://jsfiddle.net/131cmnw5/ - Now what **specifically** are you asking?

Comment: Thankyou Paulie.

In the link example in the post, the menu can be generated, dynamically, by wrapping around the menu, the different Item Templates. I am trying to do this for the .NET based CMS here, (EPiServer) but am struggling to know what the different templates do in terms of formatting.

Was after some help in placing the static menu, above, into these templates to then include in the CMS template.